# passing multi data php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php

i use this code for  on change

```
<script>
$('.BIR').change(function() {
    var id = $(this).val(); //get the current value's option
 $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        url:'assets.php',
        data:{'id':id,MainM : IR},
        success:function(data){

            $("#IRd").html(data);

        }
    });     
});
   
</script>
```

i send multi variable form this javascript to the assets.php successfully

```
<?php 
$id = $_POSt['id'];
$MainM = $_POST['MainM'];

// some php functions here to get the final data 
$Otp  = "xxxxx";
$name = "bbbbb";

?>
```

i want to pass this data back to the javascript..
if i passed one i use this

```
echo $Otp;
```

this works fine , but i want to pass this 2 variables or more .. but i don't know how to do this .. so please help.

Comment: in PHP put the data you want to `"send back to Javascript"` into an array and use `json_encode` - within the javascript callback function you can easily parse this data (jQuery does that for you)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the ideal way to be to use json. something like

```
echo json_encode(['Otp': $Otp, 'name': $name])
```

On your php side would work, and then you could use that data in your success function like such :

```
success:function(data){

        //you can then use your data like object properties, for an example
        const name = data.name;
        const Otp = data.Otp;

    }
```

Comment: Since they have `dataType: 'json'` in their ajax request, they don't need to manually parse the json using `JSON.parse(data)`. jQuery will already do that for them. Having it anyway will probably throw an error.

Comment: thanks for your replay.. but  when i tried to use
`alert(name); `
it doesn't shows any response

Comment: Ah, thanks for the heads up Magnus. Missed that indeed.

Comment: either that or you can use the updated version of my answer thanks to Magnus, I think it should work as well and it's probably a little bit more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Put the variable in an array on assets.php page like below

```
$newArray['Otp'] = "xxxxx";
$newArray['name '] = "bbbbb";

echo json_encode($newArray);
```

Add this in javascript

```
 success:function(data){
    var text = "OTP: "+data.Otp+" Name: "+data.name;

    $("#IRd").html(text);

 }
```

Comment: Since they have `dataType: 'json'` in their ajax request, they don't need to manually parse the json using `JSON.parse(data)`. jQuery will already do that for them. Having it anyway will probably throw an error.